# Set the value in the parent class and access it in the derived class

Tags: c#, parent-child, derived-class

This seems to be a very easy example, but Im puzzled and I cant make this to work.

I`m trying to retrieve the value set in Parent class "1" from the derived class by checking for "1" but it always returns else statement "3". How to access this value from within derived class ?
.
Any recommendation of how to correct this will be welcome.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent parent = new Parent();
            Child child = new Child();

            parent.SetA = 1;

            double test = child.GetA();
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }


    class Parent
    {
        protected int A;

        public int SetA
        {
            get { return A; }
            set { A = value; }
        }
    }


    class Child : Parent
    {
        public int GetA()
        {

            if (A == 1)
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else
            {
                return 3;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `child` and `parent` are two different objects (instance) so changing the state of one (e.g. setting a variable) doesn't affect the other. I'm not sure what you were expecting. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances!
You have to Call SetA on the Child

```
child.SetA = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's been pointed out, you are using two separate objects, and they each have their own copy of SetA.

If you want them to share it, you should make it static. Then every instance of a class derived from the parent will shave the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You set A on the `parent` object, not the `Parent` class. `Child` inherits everything that `Parent` has, that means you can use `child.SetA` to set the value on the child, because `Child` has a `SetA` method. You are trying to change the default value in a class, not the value on an instance of the class which is what you did.